# Pivotchart - How to include out-of-chart data for multi-period moving average trend lines

Tags: excel, pivot, moving-average

## About the chart

I have a pivot chart based on a table with historical data and seek to report only the past 12 months of data. Furthermore, the chart is connected to a slicer with a twelve month period selected. For each series of data (Green, Blue, Grey) i have added a three period moving average trend line.

### My problem

As shown below, the moving average trend lines start from the third month onward, naturally as there are insufficient data within the chart to calculate a trend before month three.

### My question

Is it possible to include data prior to the first charted period from the source table (which is available) to calculate the 3-period moving average in a pivot table?

> To clarify, i want to keep twelve periods in the bar chart, but
> include fourteen periods for the moving average calculation to achieve full
> twelve-period trend lines

[image]